# Clear HTML page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to delete portions of existing content on a page with a JavaScript function?
Like this:

```
<I WANT THIS CLEARED>
<IS THERE ANY JAVASCRIPT OR HTML STATEMENT I CAN PUT HERE?>
<I WANT THIS DISPLAYED>
```

What should I put in `<IS THERE ANY JAVASCRIPT OR HTML STATEMENT I CAN PUT HERE?>`?

I know putting `<div style="display:none"><plaintext>` after the part I want displayed will hide the end of a page, but how do I clear the beginning?

Comment: Are you asking about commenting out a section?

Comment: No, I want to use html/javascript to wipe the existing conents of a page. WOuld document.something = ""; work?

Comment: Have you considered jQuery? http://jquery.com

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to wipe the contents of the page. It's difficult to answer this as correctly as possible, without knowing any background information. While I think JQuery is great, I don't think it's the solution, just a solution.

Answer (score 21):

You can use `document.body.innerHTML = ""`. It will take out everything in the body so far as the browser processes the page. See the following example:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>This should not appear</p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.body.innerHTML = '';
        </script>

        <p>This should appear.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is, however, not a great way to accomplish this. If you want some text hidden, consider jQuery as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You can manipulate attributes and elements in javascript. So you know that the following will display only the text `the second part`.

```
<div id="top" style="display:none;">
the first part
</div>
<div id="bottom">
the second part
</div>
```

In order to dynamically manipulate these sections you could call a javascript function like the following.

```
function toggle()
{
    var top = document.getElementById("top");
    var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom");

    if (top.style.display == "none")
    {
        top.style.display = "block";
        bottom.style.display = "none";
    }
    else
    {
        top.style.display = "none";
        bottom.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

And of course, you can modify this to do much more.